# Use f-string in polars dataframe with a loop

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to create a list of new columns based on the latest column. I can achieve this by using `with_columns()` and simple multiplication. Given I want a long list of new columns, I am thinking to use a loop with an f-string to do it. However, I am not so sure how to apply f-string into polars column names.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["NY", "TK", "FD"], 
        "eat2003": [-9, 3, 8],
        "eat2004": [10, 11, 8]
    }
); df

┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ -9      ┆ 10      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 3       ┆ 11      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┘

(
    df
    .with_columns((pl.col('eat2004') * 2).alias('eat2005'))
    .with_columns((pl.col('eat2005') * 2).alias('eat2006'))
    .with_columns((pl.col('eat2006') * 2).alias('eat2007'))
)

Expected output: 
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 ┆ eat2005 ┆ eat2006 ┆ eat2007 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ -9      ┆ 10      ┆ 20      ┆ 40      ┆ 80      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 3       ┆ 11      ┆ 22      ┆ 44      ┆ 88      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 8       ┆ 8       ┆ 16      ┆ 32      ┆ 64      │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can base each of the newest columns from `eat2004`, I would suggest the following approach:

```py
expr_list = [
    (pl.col('eat2004') * (2**i)).alias(f"eat{2004 + i}")
    for i in range(1, 8)
]

(
    df
    .with_columns(expr_list)
)
```

```
shape: (3, 10)
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 ┆ eat2005 ┆ eat2006 ┆ eat2007 ┆ eat2008 ┆ eat2009 ┆ eat2010 ┆ eat2011 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ -9      ┆ 10      ┆ 20      ┆ 40      ┆ 80      ┆ 160     ┆ 320     ┆ 640     ┆ 1280    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 3       ┆ 11      ┆ 22      ┆ 44      ┆ 88      ┆ 176     ┆ 352     ┆ 704     ┆ 1408    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 8       ┆ 8       ┆ 16      ┆ 32      ┆ 64      ┆ 128     ┆ 256     ┆ 512     ┆ 1024    │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

As long as all the Expressions are independent of each other, we can run them **in parallel** in a single `with_columns` context (for a nice performance gain).  However, if the Expressions are not independent, then they must be run each in successive `with_column` contexts.

I've purposely created the list of Expressions outside of any query context to demonstrate that Expressions can be generated independent of any query.  Later, the list can be supplied to `with_columns`.  This approach helps with debugging and keeping code clean, as you build and test your Expressions.